# Why does foreach calls GetHashCode?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, gethashcode

I was surprised when I found that my override  `GetHashCode()` method of class `Foo`  is called when I am using `foreach` to travel in `IEnumerable<Foo>`. But it doesn't happens in others cases. Why?

Some parts of real code:

```
var allVolumeImagesInvolvedInMerge = volumeChainsToMerge
    .SelectMany(x => x);

var allVolumeImagesNotInvolvedInMerge = allVolumeImagesWithinCell
    .Except(allVolumeImagesInvolvedInMerge)
    .Where(vi => volumeImagesNotAllowedToDelete.ContainsFast(vi) == false);

var volumeImagesCandidatesForDeletion = allVolumeImagesNotInvolvedInMerge
    .Where(x => driverVolumeIds.Contains(x.DriverVolumeId));

var groupedVolumeImagesCandidatesForDeletion = volumeImagesCandidatesForDeletion
    .GroupBy(vi => vi.DriverVolumeId);

// here GetHashCode is called
foreach (var group in groupedVolumeImagesCandidatesForDeletion)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Post your loop and your class

Comment: Put a breakpoint on GetHashCode and then look at the call stack.

Comment: I bet the `IEnumerable<Foo>` involves [Enumerable.Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx)

Comment: My guess (from looking in reflector) is that the IEnumerable is abstracting a collection (since itself is just an interface) which uses hash codes (maybe for MoveNext()). If you show sample code, maybe you can get a more specific answer.

Comment: @EricLippert: or maybe his IEnumerable is wrapping a dictionary or hashtable.

Comment: @EladLachmi: Merely enumerating an existing hash table does not typically re-hash the entries. Join and distinct build *new* hash tables as they work.

Comment: @dtb: Or any other set operation ;p (and tolookup and todictionary)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that your `IEnumerable<Foo>` is not a collection type like `Foo[]` or `List<Foo>` but a linq query which uses deferred execution. So when you use `foreach` (or `ToList`, `Any` etc) you'll execute the query which causes all involved methods to be executed.

Maybe you are using `GroupBy`, `Distinct`, `Intersect`,`Except`, `Join` or other methods  that use your overridden `GetHashCode` and `Equals`(if `GetHashCode` returns an equal value).

Here's a simple example which reproduces it:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ID.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Foo f2 = obj as Foo;
        if (f2 == null) return false;
        return ID == f2.ID;
    }
}
```

Now this simple linq query demonstrates that `GetHashCode` is executed in the `foreach` due to the deferred execution of the `Enumerable` extension method:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> list1 = new List<Foo>() { new Foo { ID = 1 }, new Foo { ID = 2 }, new Foo { ID = 3 } };
IEnumerable<Foo> list2 = new List<Foo>() { new Foo { ID = 2 }, new Foo { ID = 3}, new Foo { ID = 4 } };
IEnumerable<Foo> inBoth = list1.Intersect(list2);

// now GetHashCode will be executed (not at list1.Intersect(list2))
foreach (Foo fDup in inBoth)
    Console.WriteLine(fDup.ID);
```

Here's a **demo**: http://ideone.com/ekttH3

Output:

```
before Intersect
after Intersect
in GetHashCode, ID=2
in GetHashCode, ID=3
in GetHashCode, ID=4
in GetHashCode, ID=1
in GetHashCode, ID=2
in Equals, ID=2
in foreach, ID=2
in GetHashCode, ID=3
in Equals, ID=3
in foreach, ID=3
```